# how can I stop a JavaScript code from executing every time the page loads

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have this translate button code. The thing is that once you use the button to translate the page, every time you reload / refresh the page the button would work automatically translating the page and would only stop if you clear the cookies on your browser!
I would like to make it only translate the page only on button press and the page would get back to the actual language on reload. Any help please?

```js
<a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('en|fr');return false;" title="French" class="gflag nturl" style="background-position:-200px -100px;"><img src="//gtranslate.net/flags/blank.png" height="16" width="16" alt="French" /></a>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
a.gflag {vertical-align:middle;font-size:16px;padding:1px 0;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-image:url(//gtranslate.net/flags/16.png);}
a.gflag img {border:0;}
a.gflag:hover {background-image:url(//gtranslate.net/flags/16a.png);}
#goog-gt-tt {display:none !important;}
.goog-te-banner-frame {display:none !important;}
.goog-te-menu-value:hover {text-decoration:none !important;}
body {top:0 !important;}
#google_translate_element2 {display:none!important;}
-->
</style>
<div id="google_translate_element2"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit2() {new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en',autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element2');}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit2"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('6 7(a,b){n{4(2.9){3 c=2.9("o");c.p(b,f,f);a.q(c)}g{3 c=2.r();a.s(\'t\'+b,c)}}u(e){}}6 h(a){4(a.8)a=a.8;4(a==\'\')v;3 b=a.w(\'|\')[1];3 c;3 d=2.x(\'y\');z(3 i=0;i<d.5;i++)4(d[i].A==\'B-C-D\')c=d[i];4(2.j(\'k\')==E||2.j(\'k\').l.5==0||c.5==0||c.l.5==0){F(6(){h(a)},G)}g{c.8=b;7(c,\'m\');7(c,\'m\')}}',43,43,'||document|var|if|length|function|GTranslateFireEvent|value|createEvent||||||true|else|doGTranslate||getElementById|google_translate_element2|innerHTML|change|try|HTMLEvents|initEvent|dispatchEvent|createEventObject|fireEvent|on|catch|return|split|getElementsByTagName|select|for|className|goog|te|combo|null|setTimeout|500'.split('|'),0,{}))
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Comment: Finally, after I spent time un-uglifing it it doesn't look like it stores cookies. The problem may come from google translate itself, or a browser plugin.

Answer (score 0):

where did you find that code?

Google have a better translation API and this...

take a look a full turorial
https://rapidapi.com/blog/google-translate-api-tutorial/

more like this

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com/language/translate/v2",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "x-rapidapi-host": "google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "<YOUR_RAPIDAPI_KEY>",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  "data": {
    "source": "en",
    "q": "Contact Form | Name | Contact Number | Email",
    "target": ""
  }

}

function fetchTranslation(){

  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {

    console.log(response);

      var translatedText = response.data.translations[0].translatedText;

      updatePlaceholders(translatedText);


  });

}
```

Comment: I'm no good with js at all so I got the code from gtranslate.io. I wouldn't use google api service because i'm looking for a free solution.. I just prefer if you can help me out with that code if possible please?

Comment: @MedazizB'a the google API is almost free https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing $20 per million characters per month... but they don't charge if you don't reach 10$ and the counter resets every month, you'd need tons of visitors using the translate before reaching that point...

Answer (score -1):

```js
<a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('en|fr');return false;" title="French" class="gflag nturl" style="background-position:-200px -100px;"><img src="//gtranslate.net/flags/blank.png" height="16" width="16" alt="French" /></a>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
a.gflag {vertical-align:middle;font-size:16px;padding:1px 0;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-image:url(//gtranslate.net/flags/16.png);}
a.gflag img {border:0;}
a.gflag:hover {background-image:url(//gtranslate.net/flags/16a.png);}
#goog-gt-tt {display:none !important;}
.goog-te-banner-frame {display:none !important;}
.goog-te-menu-value:hover {text-decoration:none !important;}
body {top:0 !important;}
#google_translate_element2 {display:none!important;}
-->
</style>
<div id="google_translate_element2"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit2() {new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en',autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element2');}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit2"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('6 7(a,b){n{4(2.9){3 c=2.9("o");c.p(b,f,f);a.q(c)}g{3 c=2.r();a.s(\'t\'+b,c)}}u(e){}}6 h(a){4(a.8)a=a.8;4(a==\'\')v;3 b=a.w(\'|\')[1];3 c;3 d=2.x(\'y\');z(3 i=0;i<d.5;i++)4(d[i].A==\'B-C-D\')c=d[i];4(2.j(\'k\')==E||2.j(\'k\').l.5==0||c.5==0||c.l.5==0){F(6(){h(a)},G)}g{c.8=b;7(c,\'m\');7(c,\'m\')}}',43,43,'||document|var|if|length|function|GTranslateFireEvent|value|createEvent||||||true|else|doGTranslate||getElementById|google_translate_element2|innerHTML|change|try|HTMLEvents|initEvent|dispatchEvent|createEventObject|fireEvent|on|catch|return|split|getElementsByTagName|select|for|className|goog|te|combo|null|setTimeout|500'.split('|'),0,{}))
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, here are some guidelines : *it is not recommended* to post code-only answers, answers should provide more explanation about the code to make it the answer more useful and are more likely to attract upvotes